# How to recognize rubbing gesture?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, touch, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I was wondering how to create some type of recognizer for a rubbing gesture.
You can see this gesture in Talking Tom Cat app and I would love to have this gesture in my clone of the app. Could you please guide me a little?

As I understand it, it is probably a swipe up and swipe down, however I don't know how to implement it the same as in the Talking Tom Cat - that means, playing animation and sound while I am rubbing the character. (I know how to play sound and animation, just don't know how to implement it with this gesture)

Also I am not sure, if it is better done by using UIGestureRecognizer or touchesBegan, Moved, Ended etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

first add gesture recognizer where you are setting up the view.

```
[myView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)]];
```

Then add code to handle gestures.

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        [self startAnimation];

    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        [self stopAnimation];
    }
}
```

hope that helps.